# Error when importing transformers/pipeline, local Python Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have no idea why I am getting this error, tried possible solutions but nope, it refuses to run in local python.

code :

```
from transformers import pipeline

# Load the text summarization pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization")
```

error :

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error 
(look up to see its traceback): module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you on? Have you tried reinstalling the latest version?

Comment: tensorflow==2.16.0 && keras==3.0

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, if you face this error, make sure you have the right version installed
I have python 3.12 installed and the supported libs were tensorflow v2.16.0 and keras v3.0 which where conflicting I guess...

Also for some reason you cant install v 2.15.0, it says not found..

I had to downgrade my python version to 3.10, & install v2.15 of tensorflow and keras to get it working :)